# simultaneous differential equations with very large matrices

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I have written a code which solves Schrodinger equation in matrix representation. Hamiltonian is a square matrix and state vectors are one-dimensional arrays. I was using numpy.matrix class and to solve coupled differential equations - ode from scipy.integrate

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
import numpy as np
```

Now I have a problem because my matrices are far more larger than 10000x10000 and I experience total RAM memory usage when running two scripts at the same time. I was hoping that maybe sparsearrays from scipy would resolve my memory consumptions as Hamiltonian and other matrices I use have lot of zeros. I don't know if I would be able then to solve differential equations. Maybe there is other method for big data matrices with complex numbers.

I would like to add, I am using vectors in some moment of time to calculate mean values, so I get just a number at the end of calculations.

Answer (score 0):

For a 10,000x10,000 matrix of double precision numbers, 800 MB (763 MiB) are used. If your method uses several matrices, that could be the problem. If the matrices are mostly empty, sparse representations are the way to go.